# Executing query_posts after wp_insert_post

Tags: wp-query

am working on a custom plugin.  I'm programmatically adding a new post in the plugin use `wp_insert_post`.  Works fine, the post gets added and I get the `$post_id`.  However, if I immediately run `query_posts` and try and reset the $wp_query to point to the new post_id I get nothing.

I feel I am not using `query_posts` correctly ... because I would think it should return the new post.

```
<?php
wp_reset_query();

$args = array(
    'post_title' => 'test post',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );

if ( $post_id != 0) {
    query_posts( array( 'post_id' => $post_id ) );
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `WP_Query` or `get_posts()` instead of `query_posts` to not mess up the main query.

Comment: kaiser have a valid point there. Go and have a look at this post, really educational and brilliant. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I tried using `get_posts` but then the post I was trying to get didn't show up in the loop and I want it to be in the loop for commenting, etc.  I have a custom URL structure that is doing some pre-processing from another databased before displaying content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `post_id` is a valid query argument - use `p` instead.